# Stop applicationDidFinishLaunching method from getting called + iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to know if there is any way to stop applicationDidFinishLaunching method of an iPhone application from getting called?

Comment: Call exit(1) in your main function :-)

Answer (score 2):

There's just a few methods who get executed before `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` like `main()` or maybe `awakeFromNib:` on the first load.

But of course anything you do to prevent `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` to be executed will render your application unusable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want to do that, but if you do then the answer probably has something to do with your main() function in main.m and creating a custom UIApplication class which you'd pass to `UIApplicationMain()`. See the docs for UIApplicationMain()